# Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries

Tags: json

```
  String json = '{'+            
    '\"FamilyMonthlyIncome\" : \"75000.00\",'+
    '\"Doyouhaveyourownhouse\" : \"Yes\",'+
    '\"SaralJeevanChannelAccess\" : \"Yes\",'+
    '\"Remarks\":\"Good\",     '+
    '\"Village\":\"Mysore\",'+
    '\"DryLandInAcre\": 5.00,'+
    '\"MobileOne\":\"9874563210\",'+
    '\"LoanAmount\":75000,     '+
    '\"RespodantName\":\"Test\",'+
    '\"Landmark\":\"Goyalvilla\",'+
    '\"NeedRemedyHelp\":\"No\",'+
    '\"IrrigatedlandInAcre\":5.00,'+
    '\"AgentMobileNo\":\"9874563211\",'+
    '\"Mainoccupationofthefamily\":\"Employed\",'+
    '\"Houshold\":5000,'+
    '\" BalanceLoanAmountOutstanding\":75000,'+
    '\"TotalLandHoldingAcre\":5.00,'+
    '\"SolutionDate\":\"1528002384000\",'+
    '\"DOBOfFamilyHead\":\"1496466264000\",'+
    '\"NameofHouseholdHead\":\"test\",     '+
    '\"SurveyDate\":\"1528002264000\",'+
    '\"Problem\":\"test\",'+
    '\"FamilyOwnsLoan\":\"Yes\",'+
    '\"State\":\"Karnataka\",   '+
    '\"District\":\"Mysore\",'+
    '\"Taluka\":\"Mysore\",'+
    '\"DoYouWatchSaralJeevanChannel\":\"Yes\",'+
    '\"HaveYouTakenSaralVaastu\":\"Yes\",'+       
    '\"NewHousebuildingaspiration\":\"Yes\",'+
    '\"StreetNm\":\"Testing\",     '+
    '\"TV\":\"Yes\",'+
    '\"CreatedDate\":\"1527964200000\",'+
    '\"Consentstatus\":\"Consent For Interview\",'+
    '\"HSC\":\"Camp\"'+           
    '\"HouseList\" : [{'+
    '\"ApproxSize\" : \"5.00\",'+
    '\"HouseAge\" : \"5\",'+
    '\"HouseType\":\"1\",'+
    '}]'+      
    '}';

system.debug('** '+json);
```

Comment: Is this your complete code? Just by copy pasting this in an anonymous window, I could see it works fine without any issue. You will need to post more details as where are you encountering the issue.

Comment: Next time try using a JSON validator https://jsoneditoronline.org/ is a good one

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs because it is not required to put '\' before '"' (quotation) in Apex. Text delimeters are ' (apostrophe) characters so " is just treat as a regular character in String and since '\' marks a special character in String Apex can't understand what character you are referring to. Remove all '\' from your string and you should be fine :)

EDIT: Also, you are a missing a ',' (coma) after "HSC": "Camp" and there's one additional comma after "HouseType": "1".